# State of parent in button in child component always null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have table with multiple columns. Each column can have modal for filtering.
I want only one modal to be visible at a time.

I pass state of component and setter of state to child component.
I can open it on click on button and I want to be able to close it by clicking same button.

```
const Parent = ()  => {
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState(null)
    return
        {columns.map(x => {
        <...>
        <Child showSearch={search} setSearch={setSearch} column={x} />
        </...>
        })}
}
    
    

const Child = ({ showSearch, setSearch, column }) => {
  const isCurrentShowed = showSearch === column.id
  const escFunction = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      setSearch(null);
    }
  }, [setSearch]);

  const toggleSearch = () => {
    console.log("Search variable is always null)
    setSearch(showSearch === column.id ? null : column.id)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', escFunction, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', escFunction, false);
    };
  }, [escFunction]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCurrentShowed && inputRef && inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [isCurrentShowed]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleSearch}>
        button
      </button>
      {isCurrentShowed && (
        <div>
          {column.render('Filter', { inputRef: inputRef})}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In child component variable `showSearch` is available and I see changed value.

In toggleSearch funtion variable `showSearch` is always null and I'm not sure why.

Comment: This variables that you called **parent state** are usually named **props**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are losing `this` reference
Swap this line:

```
<button onClick={toggleSearch}>
```

With this:

```
<button onClick={toggleSearch.bind(this)}>
```

More about context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

I think column value is not properly passed to child.

```
const Parent = ()  => {
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState(null)
    return
        {columns.map(x => {
        <...>
        <Child showSearch={search} setSearch={setSearch} column={x} />
        </...>
        })}
}
```

Comment: I just made mistake in writing this code. It was problem with binding.

Answer (score 0):

```
setSearch(showSearch === column.id ? null : column.id)
```

Care this part. Are you sure of that column.id is not null?
If it is null then always provides the equality of null === null so ternary returns null again.